# Python convert file content to unicode form

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

For example, I have a file a.js whose content is:

```
Hello, 你好, bye.
```

Which contains two Chinese characters whose unicode form is `\u4f60\u597d`
I want to write a python program which convert the Chinese characters in a.js to its unicode form to output b.js, whose content should be: `Hello, \u4f60\u597d, bye`.

My code:

```
fp = open("a.js")
content = fp.read()
fp.close()

fp2 = open("b.js", "w")
result = content.decode("utf-8")
fp2.write(result)
fp2.close()
```

but it seems that the Chinese characters are still one character , not an ASCII string like I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print u'Hello, 你好, bye.'.encode('unicode-escape')
Hello, \u4f60\u597d, bye.
```

But you should consider using JSON, via [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: in python3, encoding a string yields a bytes, so you have to encode back to ascii to get the string out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try codecs module

codecs.open(filename, mode[, encoding[, errors[, buffering]]])

```
a = codecs.open("a.js", "r", "cp936").read() # a is a unicode object

codecs.open("b.js", "w", "utf16").write(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

There two ways you can use.
first one, use 'encode' method

```
str1 = "Hello, 你好, bye. "
print(str1.encode("raw_unicode_escape"))
print(str1.encode("unicode_escape"))
```

Also you can use 'codecs' module：

```
import codecs
print(codecs.raw_unicode_escape_encode(str1))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that repr(content.decode("utf-8")) will return `"u'Hello, \u4f60\u597d, bye'"`
so `repr(content.decode("utf-8"))[2:-1]` will do the job

Comment: Warning: This does not work in Python 3.  Furthermore, it is not guaranteed that the various Python 2.x version escape Unicode strings the way you want: for instance, on my machine, repr(u"é") is "u'\\xe9'"

Answer (score -1):

you can use repr:

```
a = u"Hello, 你好, bye. "
print repr(a)[2:-1]
```

or you can use encode method:

```
print a.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
print a.encode("unicode_escape")
```

Comment: There are problems with this: see my comment to wong2's suggestion. :)